# how can i duplicate my object in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, android-recyclerview

Hi in my adapter i get some datas from firebase so in recyclerview i have a text view but i have to clone it as number of data retrieved from database and more i should do that in recyclerview for understand i will add some pictures also when i use list it comes in one row textview i wanna get the data one by one.

onbindviewholder:

```
mDatabase.orderByChild("text").equalTo(exampleItem.text).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ExampleItem exampleItem = new ExampleItem();
    
            mDatabase2.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                       for (int i =0; i<ds.getChildrenCount();i++) {
                    String body = (String) ds.child("reply").getValue();
                          exampleItem.setReply(body);
                          holder.comment.findViewById(R.id.comment);
                          holder.comment.setText(exampleItem.reply);
                       }
    
                }
```

```js
{
  "-MsqENqtJ1cZz0Qwx2T9" : {
    "-Msw22yMHJQr4xgY1iEh" : {
      "reply" : "commen"
    },
    "-Msw248--v58uGgNFM7g" : {
      "reply" : "comment"
    }
  },
  "-MsqENtNKvQRuyMATFTr" : {
    "-Msw1oJWjydrhPf-YfCv" : {
      "reply" : "comment"
    },
    "-Msw1u_BwpdVyYYfoJ-G" : {
      "reply" : "comment2"
    }
  },
  "-MsqENvkFYFWgR1nqvsY" : {
    "-Msw1rqARw5u283aNx4p" : {
      "reply" : "comment"
    },
    "-Msw1uB06rrRPO9O0P2J" : {
      "reply" : "comment"
    }
  },
  "-MsqEQ2FxK2J1udneJ_O" : {
    "-Msw1pqCdZKf9ztpjmAY" : {
      "reply" : "comment"
    },
    "-Msw1vpXbds2RvzIkgx7" : {
      "reply" : "comment3"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**my firebase adapter**

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ExampleItem> opt= new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ExampleItem>().setQuery(allfeed,ExampleItem.class).build();
               FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ExampleItem,Viewholder>adapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ExampleItem, Viewholder>(opt) {
         @Override
         protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position, @NonNull ExampleItem model) {
          
             FirebaseAuth mAuth;
             mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
             FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
             final String fuid = currentUser.getUid();
             holder.textView1.setText(model.getUsername());
             holder.textView2.setText(model.getText());
             holder.textView3.setText(model.getTime());
             holder.textView4.setText(Integer.toString(model.getStarCount()));
         @Override
         public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
             View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item,parent,false);
             Viewholder viewholder= new Viewholder(v);return  viewholder;  }};
/***************************        FİREBASEADAPTER        ***************************/
                     adapter.startListening();
                     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
    public  static  class  Viewholder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageButton img;
        EditText reply;
        ListView listView;
        TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,replyitem,comment,textView4;
        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            listView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.lst);
            textView1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            textView2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_feed);
            textView3=itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_item);
            textView4=itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            reply=itemView.findViewById(R.id.replycomment1);
            replyitem=itemView.findViewById(R.id.reply_item_que);
            comment=itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fvrtbttn);
        }
```

- 

***my xml file***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:hint="time"
                android:text="time"
                android:textColor="@color/black"

                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/opt"
                android:layout_width="17dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="&#8942;"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="name"
                android:text="username"
                android:textColor="@color/black"

                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_feed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="item"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"

                />



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/replycomment1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:inputType="textShortMessage"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/reply_item_que"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="reply"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/likes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/fvrtbttn"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_border_24"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"></ImageButton>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: i haven't any error but  i get one string from  database ("reply")  i wanna all of them but not in one line  i want one by one in line. if i use arrraylist it comes in one line all list in one string so i need clone the textview or something else. also i guess the comment which i get under question i will try that i guess it will help me

Answer (score 0):

You can add `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation in to `RecycleView`, then create separate xml file adding `TextView`. once you get data from `API` you can dynamically add xml file (which include `TextView`) into `LinearLayout`.

```
@BindView(R.id.container_comment_rating) LinearLayout mCommentRatingContainer;

public void addCommentOnDynamically(List<CommentMsg> commentMsgs){
        mContainerCommentOn.removeAllViews();

        for(CommentMsg item : commentMsgs) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_comment_on_view_work_order, null);
            TextView textMsg = (TextView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.msg_comment_on);

            if(item.getMsg() != null)textMsg.setText(item.getMsg());

            mContainerCommentOn.addView(mainView);
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks but i am new on android i can't do well.  should i use  this code block for define linearlayout in recyclerview has it be in adapter class and one more where should call this void and if you know any videos for recommend i will be so  happy. sorry

Comment: @samsa, It will be easy if you can share your adapter class and RecycleView item layout, then I can quickly help you

Comment: hi i added my adapter and item layout could you help me  please in a weeks i am working on this  i couldn't done @Dulanga